# Mongo pull in Meteor not pulling

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I've been trying to pull an array from Mongo inside of Meteor, but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm able to push to it fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's my html:

```
<ul class="schedule">
    {{#each employee.schedule}}

        <li class="schedule_item"><a class="btn listExRemove" title="Remove this name">x</a><p class="schedule_item_info">{{ . }}</p></li>  

    {{/each}}
</ul>
<div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
    <input type="text" name="schedule" value="" class="form-control"      id="schedule" placeholder="Enter the schedule" >
    <label for="item">Schedule</label>
</div>
<a href="" class="btn btn-red" id="add_event">Add</a>
```

Here is the javascript for pushing:

```
    'click #add_event': function(event, template) {

    var id = this._id; // Set equal to the current id
    var push_it = $('#schedule').val();

    Employees.update({_id:id}, {
        $push: {
            schedule: push_it
        }
    });

    console.log("It's updated");
```

And here is me pulling:

```
'click .listExRemove': function(event, template) {

    var id = this._id; // Set equal to the current id
    var the_text = $(event.target).parent().find('.schedule_item_info').text();

    Employees.update({_id: id}, {
        $pull: {
            schedule: the_text,
        }
    });

    console.log(the_text);
```

Edit:

New values are being pushed into the collection by clicking the "#add_event" button. It then pushes the value of the "#schedule" input into the "schedule" array.

Values are trying to be removed by clicking the ".listExRemove" button. It then looks in the parent container for the ".schedule_item_info" text, and saves it in the "the_text" variable. Next it should pull "the_text" from the "schedule" array, and display "the_text" in the console.

It displays "the_text" in the console, but doesn't pull it from the collection. I'm not receiving any errors, warnings, etc. I've tried pushing into different array variations and pulling without success. I've also tried replacing "the_text" with a string I know is in the array to no avail.

Comment: The only problems here should be with the values you are using. What problems are you seeing exactly? "It's not working" does not really tell anyone anything.

Comment: No errors, etc showing up. The pull just doesn't pull anything. It won't pull even when I place an actual value in place of "the_text" either. The code fully runs through, and I get "the_text" correctly displaying in the console.

Comment: How about you describe exactly what are doing and any changes and attempts with the console with an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32261142/edit) to your question. That way your problem should be clear to everyone. The code is not at fault as shown here. It will be the input.

Comment: Can you update the collection manually from the browser console or from meteor shell? It's important to remember that `$pull` only works on exact matches.

Comment: Yes, pulling from the browser console works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out since the "listExRemove" button was in an {{#each}} loop, "this._id" wasn't getting the id of the template. In order to get the id I used "template.data._id" instead.